# AutoHotKey v2.0.2: How to trigger HotKey on square bracket

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to remap the opening square bracket (`[`) to a lower case u-umlaut (`ü`) and the opening curly bracket (`{` / `Shift+[`) to the upper case U-umlaut (`Ü`) on a US keyboard layout using a [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script.

The following works very well with `;` to `ö` and `:` to `Ö` but the Variantes for `ü` and `Ü` don't. I suspect it's because a square bracket has a special meaning but there is no error about Syntax and AutoHotkey's escape Syntax with `` ` `` does not apply here.

I believe that the problem is the trigger `$[::` because the first block with `KeyWait` alone without the second `Up` part does not prevent me typing `[` while it does when I try that with `;`.

Please explain what I am doing wrong.

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
#SingleInstance Force

LongPressDelay := 220

; ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
; O-Umlaut | ; => ö und : => Ö

$;::
{
    KeyWait ";"
    return
}

$; Up::
{
    If (A_PriorHotKey = "$;" AND A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < LongPressDelay)
        Send ";"
    else
        Send "ö"
    return
}

$+;::
{
    KeyWait ";"
    return
}

$+; Up::
{
    If (A_PriorHotKey = "$+;" AND A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < LongPressDelay)
        Send ":"
    else
        Send "Ö"
    return
}


; ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
; U-Umlaut| [ => ü und { => Ü

$[::
{
    KeyWait "["
    return
}

$[ Up::
{
    If (A_PriorHotKey = "$[" AND A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < LongPressDelay)
        Send "["
    else
        Send "ü"
    return
}

$+[::
{
    KeyWait "["
    return
}

$+[ Up::
{
    If (A_PriorHotKey = "$+[" AND A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < LongPressDelay)
        Send "{"
    else
        Send "Ü"
    return
}


; EDIT: My working solution per user3419297's answer
; ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
; U-Umlaut| [ => ü und { => Ü

$SC01A::
{
    KeyWait "SC01A"
    return
}

$SC01A Up::
{
    If (A_PriorHotKey = "$SC01A" AND A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < LongPressDelay)
        Send "["
    else
        Send "ü"
    return
}

$+SC01A::
{
    KeyWait "SC01A"
    return
}

$+SC01A Up::
{
    If (A_PriorHotKey = "$+SC01A" AND A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < LongPressDelay)
        SendText "{"
    else
        Send "Ü"
    return
}
```

Script based on https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/80697-long-keypress-hotkeys-wo-modifiers/?p=689354

**Context:**

As a Developer it's super helpful to code using the US keyboard layout because all the special characters are within easy reach. As a native German speaker I'd like to access our beloved Umlauts at their traditional spots because I'm used to it.

On MacOS I solved this with Karabiner and Umlauts on long press. I want to replicate this on Windows.

Comment: NOT A SOLUTION, but possibly a workable alternative for you: I use the US-International keyboard layout. This is a standard US layout for programming, except that some keys act as "dead" keys to provide diacriticals that don't normally occur in English. The double-quote `"` as a dead key provides umlaut, so that if I type `"a`, I will get `ä`, for example. Since I do multilingual text processing as well as programming, this tends to be a useful setting.

Comment: Which AHK version are you running and how do you define LongPressDelay?

Comment: If you use AHK v2 try `SendText "{"`

Comment: @JeffZeitlin This is a great hint but I'd prefer to use the standard keys to be able to work on a system that does not conform to my settings.

Comment: @user3419297 I am working on 2.0.2. I added the head with the variable definition which works well for the other remappings. I believe the sending is not the problem because the first part with `KeyWait` alone does not suppress the key, it looks like the trigger `$[::` does not work.

Comment: Try replacing `[` by its [scan code](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys). On my system its `SC01A`.

Comment: @user3419297 That was the solution. Thank you! If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @wedi: I was looking for the same thing except I wanted to do Ctrl+[ for lowercase and Shift+Ctrl+[ for uppercase and tried to use `^SC01A::` and `+^SC01A` but couldn't make that work. Any suggestions about that?

Comment: @mattias I updated the code with my working solution. Does that help?

Comment: @wedi Yes, I tried it and for what you want it works. However it seems like Ctrl hides/disables some keys for me. Looking at the Key history I see this:

When pressing Ctrl+[
```A2  01D    a    d    2.42    LControl           
A2  01D    a    u    0.36    LControl```

When pressing Ctrl+]
```A2  01D    a    d    1.50    LControl           
DD  01B    a    d    0.14    ]                  
DD  01B    a    u    0.14    ]                  
A2  01D    a    u    0.08    LControl```

Perhaps I have to pick another key or alt instead of ctrl :/ Interestingly enough it works on my old comp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the rare case where a key has no name or the standard code doesn't work, Hotkeys can be triggered by using the 3-digit hexadecimal scan code (SC) of a key.

The scan code of a key can be determined by following the steps at [Special Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys):

- Run a script with keyboard hook
- open the AutoHotkey window (context menu in systray, Open item)
- go to View > Key History and script info
- type the key
- hit F5 to see the code

Answer (score 1):

Trying the same right here, using a different code though.

https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=99809

I managed to migrate it to V2 and changed the keys to match the German Keyboard layout.

```
[ = ü
' = ä
; = ö
- = ß
```

Please feel free to try:

```
$[::
$+[::
$'::
$+'::
$;::
$+;::
$-::
{
    umlaut_pairs := Map("$[" , "ü", "$'" , "ä", "$;" , "ö", "$-" , "ß", "$+[" , "Ü", "$+'" , "Ä", "$+;" , "Ö")
    umlaut := umlaut_pairs[A_ThisHotkey]
    Send SubStr(A_ThisHotkey,2) ; input the letter first, otherwise input order might be wrong
    KeyWait Substr(A_ThisHotkey,-1), "T0.2" ; call only the specific character without "$" or "+" and show input of the pressed key
    if(A_TimeSinceThisHotkey>200) ; if pressed more than 200ms 
        {
        Send "{BackSpace}" ; backspace previous letter 
        Send umlaut_pairs[A_ThisHotkey] ; Replace acc. to the map
        KeyWait Substr(A_ThisHotkey,-1), "T0.2"
    ;   }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your solution because you keep all umlaut mappings in one place and one gets a visual feedback when you pressed the key long enough. My solution works for me now but I might reconsider later. It would be nice if you could keep your answer updated.